# Programmatically fetch multiple code from string in Java

Tags: java

I have string looks like below, the string is joined by line-breaker. In this string, the the first 2 lines and last two lines are fixed, "public class MyClass {/n public void code() {/n"

```
String doc = 
"public class MyClass {
  public void code() {
    try (...) {
    ...
    }
  }
}"
```

I only want to take out the multiple lines code in the method code, which means no first 2 lines and last 2 lines. This is what I did in my  project:

```
String[] lines = docj.split("\\r?\\n");
String[] codes = Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, 2, lines.length - 2);
String result = String.join("\n", codes);
```

Do you have better way to fetch the string in the middle?

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch the codes"? Do you have a string with newlines in it, and you want to retain everything except the two first and two last lines? Do you want to *parse Java source code*?

Comment: Using split/copyOfRange/join is brittle code because it won't work if one reformats the source code. Likewise, writing your own grammar for a subset of Java for a parser (hand-written or generated) will be brittle because you need a scanner to arrive at the beginning of the source code you want to extract. The easiest and best solution is to just use an existing parser for full Java and a method to select the part of the parse tree you want. E.g., Antlr, grammars-v4/Java, then XPath of the parse tree. If you require comments and spacing, use intertoken information to reconstruct.

Answer (score 2):

The only *real* answer: use an existing parser framework, such as [javaparser](https://javaparser.org/).

Seriously, that simple.

Anything else means: you are spending time and energy to solve a solved problem. The result will be deficient, compared to any mature product, and it will be a constant liability in the future. You can get your tool to work with code you have in front of you right now, but the second your tool gets used to "parse" slightly different code, it will most likely break.

In case you are asking for educational purposes, then *learn* how compiler works, and what it takes to tokenize Java source code, and how to turn it into an abstract syntax tree (AST) representation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the task is meant for basic educational purposes or a quick hack (otherwise @GhostCat's answer draws first):

Already method detection, taken seriously is not so easy. Basically you have to start implementing your own syntax parser for a fraction the Java language: chop everything to single words, skip the class declaration, wait for "static", "public", "protected", "private", "synchronized", hope I didn't forget one, skip over them and the return type definition ("void", "string"...), then you are at the name, then come optional type parameters (`"<T>"`), then `"("`, then optionally method parameters etc.).

Perhaps there are  restrictions to the task, that make it less complicated. You should ask for clarification.

The problem in any case will be to find the closing braces and skip them. If you can afford to neglect such stuff as braces in strings (`string s = "ab{{c";`) or comments (`"/* {{{ */"`)it is enough to count up for each `{` occuring after e.g. `"public void code() {"` and count down for `"}"`. when the brace count is 0 and you see another `"}"`, that one can be skipped and everything until the next method declaration.

If that's not precise enough, or your requirements are of a more serious nature, you'd have to get into parsing, e.g. using [antlr](https://www.antlr.org/) or [Javaparser](https://javaparser.org/). [Here's](https://github.com/montyz/antlr4-method-extractor) a project that seems to do a similar task.

Answer (score 0):

Learning **Java Parser** takes some amount of time.  It isn't difficult, and there is a **Java Doc Documentation Page** available on the Internet.  (See Here) ... But unfortunately, there isn't a lot of text to read in the documentation pages themselves.  This class prints out the `Method Bodies` from a source-code file that is saved as a `String`.

Every method in the class is printed...

```
import com.github.javaparser.ast.*;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.stmt.BlockStmt;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.MethodDeclaration;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.visitor.VoidVisitor;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.visitor.VoidVisitorAdapter;
import com.github.javaparser.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class MethodBody
{
    static final String src = 
        "public class MyClass {"            + '\n' +
        "    public void code() {"          + '\n' +
        "        try {"                     + '\n' +
        "            /* do stuff */ "       + '\n' +
        "        }"                         + '\n' +
        "        catch (Exception e) { }"   + '\n' +
        "    }"                             + '\n' +
        "}";
   
    
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException
    {
        CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(src);
        
        VoidVisitor<?> visitor = new VoidVisitorAdapter<Void>()
        {
            public void visit(MethodDeclaration md, Void arg) 
            {
                System.out.println("Method Name: " + md.getName());

                Optional<BlockStmt> optBody = md.getBody();
                if (! optBody.isPresent()) System.out.println("No Method Body Definition\n");
                
                System.out.println("Method Body:\n" + optBody.get().toString() + "\n\n");
            }
        };
        
        visitor.visit(cu, null);
    }
}
```

The above code will print this to terminal:

```
Method Name: code
Method Body:
{
    try {
    /* do stuff */
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```